# Django page not rendering in Facebook iframe

Tags: django, facebook, iframe

i'm trying to show this django page (https://www.mm.viance.com.ec/cupones/) in a Facebook iframe and I'm getting a blank page.

I tried getting an SSL certificate, and it didn't work. I also tried bypassing de csrf_token protection.

The page renders just fine in a browser, but not inside the Facebook iframe.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox, Chrome and Safari

Comment: In google chrome console, you get something like:

Refused to display 'https://www.mm.viance.com.ec/cupones/comedor/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN' ?

Comment: probably you need something like: https://gist.github.com/barrabinfc/426829

Comment: @alexander Exactly! i get "Refused to display 'https://www.mm.viance.com.ec/cupones/comedor/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

Comment: Thanks @alexander! Following that error i got to the Django docs, in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/clickjacking/#clickjacking-prevention there is an explanation of the Clickjacking protection Django 1.6 introduces.

I just disabled that Middleware in my settings.py and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django uses Clickjacking protection with 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware'.

To allow the site to be embedded in an iframe just erase that middleware from settings.py

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/clickjacking/#clickjacking-prevention