# 'X-Frame-Options' is set to 'SAMEORIGIN' while adding custom facebook tab app

Tags: python, django, facebook

I am trying to show [this page](https://welcome-dev.herokuapp.com/) in a custom facebook tab.

It is giving me the following error:

```
Refused to display 'https://welcome-dev.herokuapp.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506774/django-page-not-rendering-in-facebook-iframe) suggests I remove 'XFrameOptionsMiddleware' from MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

When I remove that, I get the following error:

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

Reason:

```
Reason given for failure:
Referer checking failed - https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy/hv09mZVdEP8.js does not match https://welcome-dev.herokuapp.com/
```

Don't know what to do.

How to fix this?

Comment: Your app obviously checks the referrer too, and doesn’t like it when it gets form data send from a referrer different than your own domain. (Loading an app into the Facebook iframe is done by submitting a POST form that is hosted on Facebook via JavaScript.) So you need to go check where that CSRF stuff is configured within your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/_modules/django/views/decorators/csrf/#csrf_exempt) fixed the problem